# JQuery function wired select list

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

Hi everyone i have a Jquery function wired to a select list onchange. When i change the class of the select list (Error class) the onchange snap.
How i can inhibit the onchange when i change class? this is my example:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!countries}" multiselect="false" onchange="function()">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the element has the error class and if so exit the function

```
if($(this).hasClass('errorClass') return false;
```